# Mozilla Firefox doesn't display my svg

Tags: html, firefox, svg, gradient, mozilla

Why do other browsers display this svg tag, but not Mozilla Firefox.

Other browsers: Chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
     <defs id="svgDefs">
        <linearGradient id="my-gradient" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="60%" y2="0%">
                <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#BBC42A" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#EF5B2B" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path fill="none" stroke="none" id="id_svg1" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
<path fill="url('#my-gradient')" stroke="url('#my-gradient')" stroke-width="0.1" id="id_svg2" d="M11 17c0 .55.45 1 1 1s1-.45 1-1-.45-1-1-1-1 .45-1 1zm0-14v4h2V5.08c3.39.49 6 3.39 6 6.92 0 3.87-3.13 7-7 7s-7-3.13-7-7c0-1.68.59-3.22 1.58-4.42L12 13l1.41-1.41-6.8-6.8v.02C4.42 6.45 3 9.05 3 12c0 4.97 4.02 9 9 9 4.97 0 9-4.03 9-9s-4.03-9-9-9h-1zm7 9c0-.55-.45-1-1-1s-1 .45-1 1 .45 1 1 1 1-.45 1-1zM6 12c0 .55.45 1 1 1s1-.45 1-1-.45-1-1-1-1 .45-1 1z"/>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce on Firefox 55.0.2

Comment: Could you provide the computed code instead of sass and angular markup ?

Answer (score -1):

You must use `viewBox` attribute to your `<svg>` element.